# What's the most lightweight way to make custom AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax

I'm doing a nested comments system and I want to know what the most lightweight way is to make some simple AJAX calls. For example I am assuming JQuery comes with some AJAX stuff but maybe there's something a lot more light weight? XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your own little ajax function if you don't want to include jQuery. There's tons of resources out there, like [this](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html), [this](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php) or [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)